# spreadsheets api how to specify the range when there are columns with data

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

i need to append data to a spreadsheet that have defined data only in some columns so i have to complete the information in the rest cells, when i append the new data it is writed at the end of the sheet where there all the cells are blanks

here is my code to append without the auth stuff

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

data=[["data","data","data","data","https://google.com"]]
res = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId="134542fvbvfdfewdvwed4",
                            range="sheet!A1:G1",
                            valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
                            insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
                            body={"values":data}).execute()
print(res)
```

how the sheet looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to write in a specified range you will want to use the update function instead of append, and add the vertical range in the second column declaration (G523):

```
sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId="134542fvbvfdfewdvwed4",
                        range="sheet!A1:G523",
                        valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
                        body={"values":data}).execute()
```

Appending to the right of the formula cells is easiest through a second call to sheet.values().update:

```
sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId="134542fvbvfdfewdvwed4",
                        range="sheet!H1:I523",
                        valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
                        body={"values":data_part2}).execute()
```

As far as I know  you cannot skip cells or columns in a single update.

Comment: thanks for your answer but your code throws the following error "TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "insertDataOption"" ,

Comment: That is my bad for copy-pasting your code without thoroughly checking, the update function doesn't use the insertDataOption keyword, the insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS" should be removed.

Comment: thanks, but is there any way to update without specificying the range row number, i mean because every time i run the code i will need to change this, i erased the insertDataOption and set range to A:G and writed in A1:G1, did you know how yo keep track of the rows?

Comment: If you don't update it by batch, try using a iterating value (i = 0, i += 1 after writing) and use a dynamic string for the row range: f"sheet!A{i}:G{i}", this should keep track of the row if you want to write a single row at a time.